# Getting an error when I wanting to swtich from a php version (8.0) to a another php version (8.1)

Tags: php, apache

I have a Ubuntu Server 20.04 installed. I am getting this error when I am trying to run

```
sudo a2enmod php8.1
```

Getting the following error!!!
`ERROR: Module php8.1 does not exist!`

I want to disable php8.0 module and want to enable & switch to php8.1

Comment: I think you should `a2dismod php8.0` and then enable the new version

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much. I have got my answer and resolved the problem by myself.

**Run (to install libapache2-module for php8.0)**

```
sudo libapache2-mod-php8.0
```

**And then also run (to install libapache2-module for php8.1)**

```
sudo libapache2-mod-php8.1
```

After completing this process I have again tried to switch from 8.0 version to php 8.1 version and it worked

***Command One:***

```
sudo a2dismod php8.0
```

***Command Two***

```
sudo a2enmod php8.1
```